# One rail of my three rail track lighting fixture isn't working

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

## Problem

I have a 12V low-voltage track lighting fixture in my kitchen. One of the rails isn't working. If I move the bulb fixtures from the bad rail to the other rails, they light up

## History

A few days ago, one of the bulbs on the (now broken) track burnt out. The other bulbs on the track continued working. I bought another 12V bulb, it was a different sized connector, but it fit into the fixture so I tried it out anyway just to see if it would work (it didn't). I didn't notice if the other two bulbs on the rail stopped working at that point, or it if it was later.

## Question

Is it possible for a rail to burn out? I don't know much about track lighting, but I assume these rails are just conductors.

Is it possible that I shorted something to the transformer by putting in the wrong bulb?

Why would just one track stop working?

[image]

## Update

Upon further inspection, I discovered that the light sockets themselves contain the transformers (inside the white box), the rail is just a 120V conductor.

Some of the lights will come back on if I put them on a different rail and knock on them with my hand. I have yet to take a volt meter to the bad rail to confirm that it's the problem.

[image]

Comment: check corner for loose wire or worn corner may be able to replace corner
could be many things if basic track new parts can be bought. check power bet loose or no contact .check cheaper than new track and paint let us know need more info

Answer (score 1):

You probably have 4 rails there, just two happen to be in-line, on either side of the power input (gray block in center.)

Your problem is likely at the right side (in the picture) corner connector. Given that the power supply appears to be shared, the power supply would seem to be fine given the working lights - but the conductors are not conducting around the corner. Exactly why is hard to determine remotely, but that's where to look.

Comment: Don't know why you think there's four tracks but I definitely agree, it's a bad corner connector. Unless it's broke somewhere the pins just aren't making contact. High tech solution: bang on it a few times.

Comment: @Mazura Banging on it actually works, or at least on a different rail. I think I'm just going to replace the fixture .... the only problem is repairing the ceiling blemishes. The ceiling is some sort of tile (maybe polyurethane). Not sure how I'd repair it. Maybe just caulk the holes and repaint the whole ceiling ...